# How to mock exception in unmocked class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

This is base of my tested class:

```
public class MyClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    if (condition) {
      Message message = null;
      throw new MyException(message.getMessgae()); // throws NullPointerException
    }
  }
}
```

I would like test class over, whether myMethod throws MyException. message is null in test instance, because in another use instances spring bean from properties file, where value exists.
Because message returns NullPointerException, myTest not passed:

```
public class MyClassTest {
  @Test
  public void testMyMethod() {
    try {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
      myClass.myMethod();
      fail;
    } catch(MyException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

My idea is create mock of MyException or crate mock of message.getMessgae() if it is possible. Bud I don't know how...

Comment: Sorry but whaaaaaat? Show us the code you want to test and explain what behavior you're trying to test

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use **PowerMockito** to mock the parameterized constructor of `MyException` used in `MyException(message.getMessage())` such that the constructor doesn't actually try to invoke `getMessage()` on the null object.

That setup is explained in detail [here](http://benkiefer.github.io/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/).